# I have updated Xamarin.ios to 6.4.1.1 then application is giving error on Mac

Tags: xamarin.ios

When updated to this version of `xamarin.ios` there was another error which I had resolved by updating dlls `Facebook.dll`, `flurry.dll` by using command line tool provided by Rolf. Now application is giving following errors. Please provide some solution regarding this and also want to know how to update dlls of framework for e.g. `monotouch.dll`.

Errors are,
1)`/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/ScrapBoom-Stable/ScrapBoom.iPhone/ScrapBoom.iPhone/Screens/iPhone/AddDocument/ImageCroppingScreen.cs(38,38): Error CS0012: The type System.Drawing.Size' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012) (ScrapBoom.iPhone)`

2)`/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/ScrapBoom-Stable/ScrapBoom.iPhone/ScrapBoom.iPhone/Screens/iPhone/AddDocument/ImageCroppingScreen.cs(14,14): Error CS0012: The type System.Drawing.PointF' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012) (ScrapBoom.iPhone)`

3)`/Users/volgainfotech/Projects/ScrapBoom/Kiln/ScrapBoom-Stable/ScrapBoom.iPhone/ScrapBoom.iPhone/Screens/iPhone/AddDocument/ImageCroppingScreen.cs(30,30): Error CS0012: The type MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. Consider adding a reference to assembly monotouch, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' (CS0012) (ScrapBoom.iPhone)`

I had refered this forum also,
http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1475/changes-to-assembly-strongnames-in-xamarin-ios-6-2-0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't update all your references with my tool (note that you should not update platform assemblies like monotouch.dll, only your own or other third-party assemblies).

The lines where the errors occur likely uses API from this dll you forgot to update.

Comment: but after updating all assemblies it is giving the error that,Error MT9000: This version was released after your subscription expired (27-06-2013 08:08:14). (MT9000) (ScrapBoom.iPhone)

Comment: @user1468544: that is a completely different problem - you need to renew your Xamarin.iOS subscription. If you have any problems related to subscription renewal (or other licensing related issues), please contact support@xamarin.com.